# python AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Race'

Tags: python

Whenever I try to run the following code I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\NASCAR (1).py", line 29, in <module>
DriverList.Race()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Race'
```

So I have clearly messed up something with my list. This program is supposed to simulate a race and then after a car has gone 500 miles it will print out the winners name and sponsor which is where I am having a problem. How can I fix this attribute error?

```
from random import randint

class Car:
    def __init__(self, DriverName, SponsorName):
        RaceWinner = False
        self.OdometerTotal = 0
        self.Time = 0
        self.Driver = DriverName
        self.Sponsor = SponsorName
    def Race(self):
        LastSpeed = 0
        while self.OdometerTotal < 500:
            self.Time += 1
            self.CurrentSpeed = randint(1, 120)
            self.OdometerTotal +=(self.CurrentSpeed / 60 * self.Time) + ((self.CurrentSpeed - LastSpeed) / (60 * self.Time))
            LastSpeed = self.CurrentSpeed
            if self.OdometerTotal >= 500:
                print(self.Driver, "sponsored by", self.Sponsor, "was the winner.")
                RaceWinner = True
                return RaceWinner
    def Winner(self):
        if RaceWinner == True:
            print(self.Name)
            print(self.Sponsor)

DriverList = [Car("Aric Almirola","Richard Petty Racing"),Car("Marcos Ambrose", "Richard        Petty Motorsports"),Car("Greg Biffle", "Roush Fenway Racing"),Car("Dave Blaney", "Tommy Baldwin     Racing"),Car("Clint Bowyer", "Michael Waltrip Racing"),Car("Jeff Burton", "Richard Childress Racing"),Car("Kurt Thomas Busch", "Furniture Row Racing"),Car("Kyle Busch", "Joe Gibbs Racing"),Car("Liz LeMuiex", "Hendrick Motorsports"),Car("Dale Earnhardt Jr.", "Hendrick Motorsports"),Car("Carl Edwards", "Roush Fenway Racing"),Car("David Gilliland", "Front Row Motorsports"),Car("Jeff Gordon", "Hendrick Motorsports"),Car("Denny Hamlin", "Joe Gibbs Racing"),Car("Kevin Harvick", "Richard Childress Racing"),Car("Sam Hornish Jr", "Penske Racing"),Car("Jimmie Johnson", "Hendrick Motorsports"),Car("Kasey Kahne", "Hendrick Motorsports"),Car("Matt Kenseth", "Roush Fenway Racing"),Car("Brad Keselowski", "Penske Racing")]

while True:
    DriverList.Race()
        if RaceWinner in DriverList:
            print("The winner is", DriverList.Winner())
            break

DriverList = ["Aric Almirola", "Marcos Ambrose", "Greg Biffle", "Dave Blaney", "Clint Bowyer", "Jeff Burton", "Kurt Thomas Busch", "Kyle Busch", "Liz LeMuiex", "Dale Earnhardt Jr.", "Carl Edwards","David Gilliland", "Jeff Gordon", "Denny Hamlin", "Kevin Harvick", "Sam Hornish Jr", "Jimmie Johnson", "Kasey Kahne", "Matt Kenseth", "Brad Keselowski"]

SponsorList = ["Richard Petty Racing", "Richard Petty Racing", "Roush Fenway Racing", "Tommy Baldwin Racing", "Michael Waltrip Racing", "Richard Childress Racing", "Furniture Row Racing", "Joe Gibbs Racing", "Hendrick Motorsports", "Hendrick Motorsports", "Roush Fenway Racing", "Front Row Motorsports","Hendrick Motorsports", "Joe Gibbs Racing", "Richard Childress Racing", "Penske Racing", "Hendrick Motorsports", "Hendrick Motorsports", "Roush Fenway Racing", "Penske Racing"]
```

Comment: No, your list is fine. It's your program that's unsalvageable.

Comment: Note that the first Car called will always "Win" as you do not return to do any other processing until that car passes 500.

Answer (score 0):

`DriverList` is a list of objects. You need to select objects from that list to call function `race`.

```
#Code--------
num = 0
while num<(len(DriverList)-1):
    DriverList[num].Race()
    num+=1
if RaceWinner in DriverList:
    print("The winner is", DriverList.Winner())
    break
```